How to implement Firebase Realtime Database with complex data in .NET MAUI
I am using NET MAUI and Firebase Realtime Database. I am uploading some user data in Firebase Realtime Database and I fetch all my data from my view model but it's taking too much time to load and when I add some more new data then it takes too much time to reflect in my app. How can I remove this delay time to make my app faster.
The code which I used to fetch the data from Firebase Realtime Database :
public ProfilePageViewModel(INavigation navigation, FirebaseManager _firebaseManager)
  {
      firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient(DatabaseUrl);
      Navigation = navigation;
      firebaseManager = _firebaseManager;
      PaymentMethods = new ObservableCollection<PaymentModel>();
      LoadUserData();
  }

  private async void LoadUserData()
  {
      await FetchUserDataAsync();
  }
  public async Task FetchUserDataAsync()
  {
      UserId = Preferences.Get("LocalId", string.Empty);
      IsLoading = true;
     
      var observable = firebaseClient
      .Child("UserData")
      .Child(UserId)
      .AsObservable<UserDataModel>();

      observable.Subscribe(user =>
      {
          UserData = user.Object;
          FullName = UserData.FirstName + " " + UserData.LastName;
      }, error =>
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Error while fetching user data: " + error.Message);
      });
      IsLoading = false;
  }
}


Whenever reasoning/asking about time to load some data, include information about how much data you're loading (so the size of the JSON in this case), the bandwidth and latency of the connection and the device used, and measure how long the data load takes exactly in your code (don't just say "too much time"). Without those, there isn't much anyone can do but say "either load less data or get a faster internet connection or device".

What do you consider “slow”?  And are you sure the FB query is the bottleneck?
